# Null dereferencing within VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm in the process of reviewing many of our applications. One application came back with quite a few null deference issues. It is worth mentioning is that I am quite unfamiliar with VB.NET so bear with any issues I may relay with my code.

```
Public Sub SomeMethod()
    Try
        PerformLog("Entering SomeMethod")
        Dim intTemp As Short

        Erase gstrFieldWhatever //Defined earlier: Public gstrFieldWhatever() As String

        ...

        intTemp = intTemp + 1
        ReDim Preserve gstrFieldWhatever(intTemp)
        gstrFieldWhatever(intTemp) = "Z*L-"
```

The analyzer, Fortify in this case, is reporting that `Erase gstrFieldWhatever` will cause a potential null exception when we try to call it later at `gstrFieldWhatever(intTemp) = "Z*L-"`. However, we using [`ReDim Preserve gstrFieldWhatever(intTemp)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement) should create a new array. If this is the case, why would the analyzer indicate a potential null dereference issue?

Comment: The `Erase` keyword is a holdover from the VB6 era, and it's there to make porting old code easier. It's not good practice in .Net. Same with `ReDim Preserve`. In most cases, that means you should have a collection rather than an array.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah... is there a better way of performing a similar action as the Erase keyword? Am I asking the wrong question (should I be asking how to use a collection)?

Comment: VB.Net would typically just redeclare the array (without `Preserve`)  or -- even better -- use a `List(Of String)` and call it's `.Clear()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gstrFieldWhatever` is a public field. There's a risk if this object is used in multi-threaded code, because the field could be accessed between when it is freed and when it is ReDimmed.

In most cases, the use of `ReDim Preserve` indicates a place where you really want a collection like `List(Of String)`, however, I understand if that change might cascade into other areas of the code.

Comment: Well that's good enough an excuse for me. Sounds like tweaking to use collections instead of arrays might be a good choice for the application.

Comment: I'll confirm that with your answer, we were able to resolve the issues. Thanks again!